# How to route for a react-router app using express?

Tags: reactjs, express, routes

So I have a backend running in expressjs and I have multiple routes on it. Now I just followed [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) tutorial to set up a RESTful *api* on express. Now I want to switch to full react on the frontend, so that I will have an api running in the backend to get things from the database and am thinking using `fetch` from react to get that data. I saw many people say that is the best way to do it. But now there is an issue, I am not sure how to route for this. I have `react-router` setup so I am assuming I would use that. But how can I serve these files to the client side? How can I make sure every route *except* `/api` routes just serve my js files? Like I have a built folder already with an `index.html` and `main<hash>.js`. I am running them easily but how can I intergrate them with express? I was not able to find any answers to this. **How can I route for a reactjs app to be served using expressjs**? and also I saw a tutorial telling me to use a `*` route but that means even my api routes will only point to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways basically to render an application.
One is Server Side Rendering, the other one is Client Side rendering and the third one is Isomorphic rendering.

So if you are defining your routes in Nodejs and navigating the application through those routes than it will be entirely server side rendering.

> I saw a tutorial telling me to use a * route but that means even my
>   api routes will only point to that. ? How can I make sure every route
>   except /api routes just serve my js files?

Regarding this what you can do is

```
server.get('/api', (req, res, next) => {
    //You can handle the request here
})  

server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    //You can handle the request here
})
```

You can define your route in this order.So by this way any call to the '/api' will be  handled by the first route and all the other request will be handled by the second route.

> Now I want to switch to full react on the frontend, so that I will
>   have an api running in the backend to get things from the database and
>   am thinking using  fetch from react to get that data

Here you dont need this.It will be an client side rendering completely

```
    server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
        //You can handle the request here
    })
```

For this you can create an react app from scratch or use some boilerplate (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).

There you can define all the routing and  simply call the url `http://localhost/api/xxxx` and get the data and you can use this data in the frontend.In this case there will be a Nodejs Server which will be serving the frontend and the expressjs server will he hosting the 'api' service to get data  from.

> I have react-router setup so I am assuming I would use that. But how
>   can I serve these files to the client side?`
>
> How can I route for a reactjs app to be served using expressjs?

The Reactjs app when compiled is a combination of static files comprising mainly of html, css, javascript. If you want your app to be served by your express.js server then you need to use isomorphic rendering. It is by far the best approach for rendering application as it is good for SEO and initial fast page load. It comes at the cost of a complicated setup. In this case, whenever the page refreshes or the first request comes, express will serve the first page (index.html) and index.html will contain the required static(bundled) js and css files for client side rendering. The first rendering will be done by the express server and the subsequent rendering will be done by browser itself.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! That helped me a lot. So basically I will be using `res.sendFile()` on request `*` to send the `index.html` which will have bundled js and the front end routes will be carried out by react-router(that is what I understood). And I have an `/api` endpoint before the `*`. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes u can start as that.You will know many things once u start doing it.

Comment: I have the same issue but somehow the service worker in create-react-app is still treating it as react-router. When the service worker is unregistered that is the only time it will recognize it as express router and not react router. I haven't figured a workaround yet...

Comment: Just an update, solved the server/client router issue with the answe here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3299#issuecomment-355428987 :)